# Finite limit of function in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given
$$y'(x)=a(x)y(x)+b(x);$$
$y(x_0)=y_0$, $a(x)=k>0$, $b(x)\leq M e^{\epsilon x}$, $0<\epsilon<k$, $M>0$, then $\frac{y(x)}{e^{k x}}$ approaches a finite limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$ with $x_0=0$, $x_2=\infty$.

Comment: So, you have the differential equation (multiplying your given equation by $e^{-\epsilon x}$ and setting $b(x)e^{-\epsilon x}=c(x)$): $$e^{-\epsilon x}y'(x)=e^{-\epsilon x}ky(x)+c(x)$$ where $c(x) \le M$. You can already see (almost) the derivative of $\dfrac{y(x)}{e^{\epsilon x}}$ there.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry but I cannot see how $\frac{y(x)}{e^{\epsilon x}$ approach a finite limit. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you sure the equation is not missing a minus sign, like $$y'(x)=-a(x)y(x)+b(x)\,?$$ Then you get an asymptotic curve $y_a(x)=\frac{b(x)}{a(x)}$ and the equation at every time moves the state towards this asymptotic.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full solution (see the comments by @LutzLehmann on the post) but here is what I could prove. Multiply the whole equation by $e^{-\epsilon x}$ to get $$e^{-\epsilon x}y'(x)=e^{-\epsilon x}ky(x)+c(x)$$ where $c(x)=b(x)e^{-\epsilon x}\le M$ as given. The above equation gives $$e^{-\epsilon x}y'(x)-\epsilon e^{-\epsilon x}y(x)=e^{-\epsilon x}(k-\epsilon)y(x)+c(x)$$ so, taking $h(x)=e^{-\epsilon x} y(x)$, the LHS above is $h'(x)$ and the equation can be rewritten as $$h'(x)=(k-\epsilon)h(x)+c(x)$$ Take note that you want $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}h(x)$ to be finite. $\qquad \qquad \qquad (*)$ 
 Now, from the condition $0<\epsilon < k$, you have $p=k-\epsilon>0$, so you can rewrite the last equation as $$\begin{aligned} h'(x)-ph(x)&=c(x) \\ \implies e^{-px}h'(x)-pe^{-px}h(x)&=e^{-px}c(x) \\ \implies \dfrac{d}{dx}(e^{-px}h(x))&=e^{-px}c(x) \qquad \qquad (1)\end{aligned}$$ Now, the RHS above is bounded above as follows: $$\begin{aligned}e^{-px}c(x)&\le Me^{-px}\ (\because c(x)\le M \text{ from above})\\ 
\implies \int_{x_0}^{\infty} e^{-px}c(x)dx &\le \int_{x_0}^{\infty} Me^{-px}dx \\
\implies \int_{x_0}^{\infty} \dfrac{d}{dx}(e^{-px}h(x))dx & \le M\left[-\dfrac{e^{-px}}p\right]_{x_0}^{\infty} \ (\text{from }(1))\\
\implies \left[e^{-px}h(x)\right]_{x_0}^{\infty} & \le M\left(0+\dfrac{e^{-px_0}}p\right) \\ 
\implies \lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{-px}h(x))-h(0) & \le \dfrac{M}p \ (\because x_0=0) \\
\implies \lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{-px}h(x)) & \le \dfrac{M}p+y \ \left(\because h(0)=e^{-\epsilon \cdot 0}y(0)=y\right) \qquad (2)\\
\implies \lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{-kx}y(x))&\le \dfrac{M}p+y \qquad \qquad \qquad (3)\end{aligned}$$
We want the last step to have $\epsilon$ instead of $k$, and this is the closest I could get.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I am sorry, that was a bad mistake.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Is the solution so far correct? Also, following from your comment on the post, does "*... the equation at every time moves the step towards ....*" mean taking the derivative of $y(x)$ *every time*? My understanding of differential equations is inadequate, so I hope you bear with me.

Comment: Yes, the steps are now correct. As the example $h'=h+1$ shows, you can not expect more. // For the remark, "every time", think of the Euler method with infinitesimal time steps. The sign on the right side is then negative above the slowly moving equlibrium/asymptote and positive below, so that the asymptote behaves nearly like a stable stationary point. The solution will move in the shadow of that curve, following a little behind it.

Comment: your answer is correct, its just my problem has a typo. Thank you sir, this helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for $y'(x)$ is
\begin{eqnarray*}
y(x)&=&y_0 e^{\int a(x) dx} + \int_0^{\infty} e^{\int_s^x a(u)du} b(s) ds \\
&=& y_0 e^{\int k dx} + \int_0^{\infty} e^{\int_s^x k du} b(s) ds, \textrm{ since } a(x)=k \\
&=& y_0 e^{kx} + \int_0^x e^{kx-ks} b(s) ds \\
&=& e^{kx} \left( y_0 +  \int_0^{\infty} e^{-ks} b(s) ds   \right) \\
&\leq& e^{kx} \left( y_0 +  \int_0^{\infty} e^{-ks} Me^{\epsilon s} ds   \right), \textrm{ since } b(x)\leq Me^{\epsilon x} \\
&=& e^{kx} \left( y_0 +  M \int_0^{\infty} e^{(\epsilon-k)s} ds   \right) \\
&=& e^{kx} \left( y_0 +  M \left[ \frac{e^{(\epsilon-k)s}}{\epsilon - k} \right]_0^{\infty}   \right) \\
&=& e^{kx} \left( y_0 - \frac{M}{\epsilon-k} \right) \\
&=& e^{kx} \left( y_0 + \frac{M}{k-\epsilon} \right).
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{e^{kx}}$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
& & \frac{y(x)}{e^{kx}} \leq \frac{e^{kx}}{e^{kx}} \left( y_0 + \frac{M}{k-\epsilon} \right) \\
& \Rightarrow & \frac{y(x)}{e^{kx}} \leq \left( y_0 + \frac{M}{k-\epsilon} \right).
\end{eqnarray*}
Applying limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{y(x)}{e^{kx}} &\leq& \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( y_0 + \frac{M}{k-\epsilon} \right)\\
&=& y_0 + \frac{M}{k-\epsilon}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, as $ x \to \infty$, $\frac{y(x)}{e^{kx}}$ approaches a finite limit.